# How can I login my website with Google Account?

Tags: magento2, email, google, social

We have a Magento 2 website and want to implement the feature where the user can login using their Google Account as below if already they logged-in their Gmail/Google account on the system.

[image]

Can anyone please guide me here?

Comment: Do you have `Google API client ID` ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes, I have the API Client

Comment: OK, I manage to add login window as you describe in your screen shot but not able to login..

Comment: @Pawan, please tell me the steps and where did you add the Google Client ID in Magento 2?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Ready extension launched https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-one-tap-login.html

Answer (score 3):

As I understood you want to add Google onetap login i.e https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

1. You need `Google API client ID` (https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid) which should looks like: 1234567890-abc123def456.apps.googleusercontent.com
2. Load `One Tap client library` (https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/load-one-tap-client-library)

In magento we can add JS via XML, Create :

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" src_type="url"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="onetap" template="Magento_Customer::onetap.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Display Google One Tap (https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-google-one-tap)

In magento we need to Create phtml we defined in layout to display one tap, Create:

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/onetap.phtml

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_Google_API_client_ID"
     data-login_uri="https://your.domain/your_login_endpoint"
     data-your_own_param_1_to_login="any_value"
     data-your_own_param_2_to_login="any_value">
</div>
```

**Note:** Above will display Google one tap login to your Magento login page.After that we need to check response from Google and based on response we can login, create account

**I will keep update on this answer as I am working on it..**

Comment: Thanks. I will try and please update me the complete concept here. Now, I'm upvoting you.

Comment: Sure, working on remaining part and update soon.Please let me know if have any issue till display login tap.

Comment: Please let me know @Pawan

Comment: sure, will try and update..

Comment: Is the Google Tap login works on http?

Comment: only on localhost, for TLD you need SSL

Comment: I have tried as you said but the One Tap Sign in is not displaying in frontend. I have tried it on localhost

Comment: there can be many reason like, JS is not loading, phtml not rendering, wrong client id etc. please debug one by one.

Comment: did you get login window ?

Comment: No I haven't got the result. I'm trying in localhost. I have followed as per your information. Please guide me

Comment: Have you completed the remaining part of one tap login?

Comment: Hi Pavan, have you finished implementing this, can you guide me please. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Purna, if you want to checkout this extension in case https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-one-tap-login.html

Comment: @GauravJain Thanks for the link. Is there any free plugins for one tap sign in?

Comment: @Siva I couldn't find any free at the moment

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is called "One-tap sign-up and auto sign-in on websites". **Ref -** https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web

You'll have to load a library provided by google to use it.
You can find a detailed guide of implementing it here - https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

Note that you'll have to follow all the steps in "Get Started" tab and for additional features you can turn to "Advanced Topics" tab.

Comment: I have already done all the things but how can I enable the one tap singin? Please guide me

Comment: what issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: make sure you go through https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/features

Comment: Yes, I have followed the link which you have shared but its now working. One thing is I have installed the Social Login extension and there is an option to put the API key and Secret. I have put the keys there but it will works for One Tap Login or I need to put that separately. If yes, where I have to put them.

Comment: You only need Google client ID to make it work, no need of for api key and secret.

Comment: Also please mark the answers as the solution if it helped you.

Comment: Where I have to put the Google client ID in Magento 2?

Comment: I am assuming you've done custom implementation of the feature, and if so you're passing the Google client ID in js. For this you'll have to make a custom configuation in admin using system.xml and fetch in the block and pass it your js using "text/x-magento-init" config.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Kumar

Answer (score 0):

There Are two Steps

- Create an App on Google and Get API credentials for OAuth API
- Install [MagePlaza Social Login](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-login-extension/) on Store and Add Cretiendtals in Configuration That's All it

Comment: Thanks @Waqar Ali. But I have already installed the Social Login Plugin and the concept which I'm looking for differ from the social login. If the user already logged-in the Gmail on the system, they can use the google account on my website as the image in question

Comment: the social login plugin won't have this kind of feature. Please suggest me here

Comment: If you are a Store Owner you can request this feature if you are developer you can easily get this Feature in any other PHP Project just need to implement this In Magento

Comment: Can you please point me out how can I implement as like this? I have already created an App and using the API credentials but only thing is I want to show as like in the pic.

Comment: okay let me have a look

Comment: Is there any suggestion for me?