# Magento 2: One Tap Sign-in

Tags: magento2, login, google-api

I would like to implement the Google One Tap Login on my website but its not working.

I have followed the below guide for Google One Tap Login:

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

To Implement it in Magento, I have followed the below guide:

[How can I login my website with Google Account?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311679/how-can-i-login-my-website-with-google-account)

But nothing works. Can anyone please guide me to implement the Google One Tap?

Comment: HI Tim, Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Here is the solution ready extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-one-tap-login.html